# Python loop while collecting data

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, counter, average

I have an NFL simulator that runs and spits out a score for both teams based on a couple variables, however I would like the simulator to be more accurate. I am trying to get it to run 100 times, counting the number of times each team won, while also keeping track of the scores for each team in each simulation and then producing their avg score. I am a little lost on how to collect the score and then add them all together and divide by 100. Also, how to assign a 'win' to a team in the loop.

```
    def calc(self):
        selected_indexA = teams.index(self.var1.get())

        PowerRankA = power_rankings[selected_indexA]
        WinPercA = winning_percentage[selected_indexA] * 100
        LuckA = random.randrange(0,25)
        HomeBonus = 10

        selected_indexB = teams.index(self.var2.get())

        PowerRankB = power_rankings[selected_indexB]
        WinPercB = winning_percentage[selected_indexB] * 100
        LuckB = random.randrange(0,25)
        HomeBonus = 10

        TeamAScore = (PowerRankA + WinPercA + LuckA) / 3
        TeamBScore = (PowerRankB + WinPercB + LuckB + HomeBonus) / 3

        self.lblScoreA["text"] = int(TeamAScore)
        self.lblScoreB["text"] = int(TeamBScore)

    def sim(self):
        count = 0
        while count <= 100:
            if TeamAScore > TeamBScore:
                self.lblWinsA = 1
            else:
                self.lblWinsB = 1
            count +=1
```

Comment: Please only send the required code to be investigated .. Thanks!

Comment: You can use something like `for i in range(100)` to run your loop 100 times, and you should be able to create a variable with which to keep track of each team's cumulative score. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you please narrow down the code, just for the averaging part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate 100 games and sum scores in `for` loop and than divide it by 100

```
TeamAScore = 0
TeamBScore = 0

TeamAWins = 0
TeamBWins = 0
NoWins = 0

for i in range(100):
    LuckA = random.randrange(0,25)
    LuckB = random.randrange(0,25)

    ScoreA = (PowerRankA + WinPercA + LuckA) / 3
    ScoreB = (PowerRankB + WinPercB + LuckB + HomeBonus) / 3

    TeamAScore += ScoreA
    TeamBScore += ScoreB

    if ScoreA > ScoreB:
        TeamAWins += 1
    elif ScoreA < ScoreB:
        TeamBWins += 1
    else:
        NoWins += 1


TeamAScore /= 100.0
TeamBScore /= 100.0

print "Avg. Score for TeamA:", TeamAScore, " number of Wins:", TeamAWin
print "Avg. Score for TeamB:", TeamBScore, " number of Wins:", TeamBWin
print "No Wins:", NoWins
```

If you need to remeber all scores use `list` and `.append()`

```
TeamA_All_Scores = [] # list for all scores
TeamB_All_Scores = [] # list for all scores

TeamAWins = 0
TeamBWins = 0
NoWins = 0

for i in range(100):
    LuckA = random.randrange(0,25)
    LuckB = random.randrange(0,25)

    ScoreA = (PowerRankA + WinPercA + LuckA) / 3
    ScoreB = (PowerRankB + WinPercB + LuckB + HomeBonus) / 3

    TeamA_All_Scores.append(ScoreA)
    TeamB_All_Scores.append(ScoreB)

    if ScoreA > ScoreB:
        TeamAWins += 1
    elif ScoreA < ScoreB:
        TeamBWins += 1
    else:
        NoWins += 1


TeamAScore = sum(TeamA_All_Scores) / 100.0
TeamBScore = sum(TeamB_All_Scores) / 100.0

print "Avg. Score for TeamA:", TeamAScore, " number of Wins:", TeamAWin
print "Avg. Score for TeamB:", TeamBScore, " number of Wins:", TeamBWin
print "No Wins:", NoWins
print "TeamA All Scores:", ",".join(TeamA_All_Scores)
print "TeamB All Scores:", ",".join(TeamB_All_Scores)
```